# Sum inner join if didn't exist = 0

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have a task to make sum of this and I want to get sum value = 0 if it didn't match with the join table.

```
SELECT 
    TCS.departement,
    TCS.category,
    FORMAT ( BE.DT , 'yyyy-MM' ) AS CURR_MONTH,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE 
            WHEN BE.DFROM IN('SEWING','WEAVING','FORMING',
            'DYE','HSM','INSPECTION','WOVEN') 
            AND BE.DFROM = BE.DTO THEN BE.QTY
        END
        ),0) AS TOTAL_LOSS_PROSES,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE
            WHEN  DFROM != 'SEWING' THEN QTY 
            WHEN  DFROM != 'WEAVING'THEN QTY 
            WHEN  DFROM != 'FORMING'THEN QTY 
            WHEN  DFROM != 'DYE'THEN QTY 
            WHEN  DFROM != 'HSM'THEN QTY 
            WHEN  DFROM != 'INSPECTION'THEN QTY 
            WHEN  DFROM != 'WOVEN'THEN QTY 
            ELSE 0 
        END),0) AS TOTAL_LOSS_SEMUA
    FROM TBL_CATEGORY TCS
    INNER JOIN  
    B_ENTRYLOSS BE ON  TCS.category = BE.LOSSCAT
    WHERE 
    FORMAT ( BE.DT , 'yyyy-MM') BETWEEN '2022-04' AND '2022-06'
    GROUP BY TCS.departement, TCS.category, 
    FORMAT ( BE.DT , 'yyyy-MM') 
    order by category ASC, CURR_MONTH DESC;
```

my result :

```
    |departement|   category   |CURR_MONTH|TOTAL_LOSS_PROSES|TOTAL_LOSS_SEMUA|
    |:----------|:-------------|:---------|:----------------|:---------------|
    |WEAVING    |    Anyaman   |  2022-04 |      88.80      |   181.69       |
    |WEAVING    |    Anyaman   |  2022-05 |      86.64      |   126.02       |
    |WEAVING    |    Anyaman   |  2022-06 |      80.80      |   117.55       |
    |DYE        |    Belang    |  2022-04 |      0.00       |   0.67         |
    |DYE        |    Belang    |  2022-05 |      0.00       |   0.67         |
    |WEAVING    |Benang Keluar |  2022-05 |      24.11      |   24.11        |
    |WEAVING    |Benang Keluar |  2022-06 |      7.65       |   7.65         |
```

expected result:

```
|departement|   category   |CURR_MONTH|TOTAL_LOSS_PROSES|TOTAL_LOSS_SEMUA|
|:----------|:-------------|:---------|:----------------|:---------------|
|WEAVING    |    Anyaman   |  2022-04 |      88.80      |   181.69       |
|WEAVING    |    Anyaman   |  2022-05 |      86.64      |   126.02       |
|WEAVING    |    Anyaman   |  2022-06 |      80.80      |   117.55       |
|DYE        |    Belang    |  2022-04 |      0.00       |   0.67         |
|DYE        |    Belang    |  2022-05 |      0.00       |   0.67         |
|DYE        |    Belang    |  2022-06 |      0.00       |   0.00         |
|WEAVING    |Benang Keluar |  2022-04 |      0.00       |   0.00         |
|WEAVING    |Benang Keluar |  2022-05 |      24.11      |   24.11        |
|WEAVING    |Benang Keluar |  2022-06 |      7.65       |   7.65         |
```

Please help me with this code, should I use `coalesce` to change `isnull`?

why i didn't use a single expression to both sum, because the result i get with the query form single expression didn't match

```
SUM(CASE WHEN  DFROM NOT IN( 'SEWING','WEAVING','FORMING','DYE','HSM','INSPECTION','WOVEN') 
 THEN QTY 
 ELSE 0
```

result :

```
        |departement|   category   |CURR_MONTH|TOTAL_LOSS_PROSES|TOTAL_LOSS_SEMUA|
        |:----------|:-------------|:---------|:----------------|:---------------|
        |WEAVING    |    Anyaman   |  2022-04 |      88.80      |   27.20       
        |WEAVING    |    Anyaman   |  2022-05 |      86.64      |   22.87       
        |WEAVING    |    Anyaman   |  2022-06 |      80.80      |   13.70       
        |DYE        |    Belang    |  2022-04 |      0.00       |   0.67         
        |DYE        |    Belang    |  2022-05 |      0.00       |   0.67         
        |WEAVING    |Benang Keluar |  2022-05 |      24.11      |   0.00 
        |WEAVING    |Benang Keluar |  2022-06 |      7.65       |   0.00
```

its different from the first query when i put whole list of case branches, i still didn't know the reason why got different results

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Comment: `coalesce` and `isnull` are functionally equivalent here.

Comment: i try to do some search, some of their use coalesce and isnull, but the result didnt like what i need

Comment: Functionally they are the same but why are you using one with a single case expression and IN but the other one is a whole list of case branches? For the question at hand it isn't clear what you want. Maybe a left join?

Comment: I try using single case expression to another one, but the results different, i try using left join and right join, but the category that didn't match with inner join didn't appear

Comment: Sample data would go a LONG way to making this clear. Just saying "the results different" is fairly useless. What does that mean?

Comment: possibly you need a `LEFT JOIN` and move the `BE.DT` in the `WHERE` condition to `JOIN` condition

Comment: @Squirrel cab you show me how, i didn't understand

Comment: We have no idea what is wrong or what is the issue with your query yet.  You need to provide some sample data and explain what is wrong with your current query.

Comment: @SeanLange i put the result when i try 1 expression data for both sum

Comment: @Squirrel i want  to have 0 as the default value returned when the inner join table not exist, like my expectation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no data for the month "2000-06" in the inner joined table then there will be no row produced by the `group by` clause, and hence it won't matter if you use `ISNULL` or `COALESCE` (because there simply is no row for either function to work with).

So you must "force" every wanted row to exist, then "outer join" your data . Below you can see that I have formed 3 month values in a "derived table" that is used with a `cross join` which forces every "month" to be present in the result. Then these "months" are then used as part of the join condition to your loss source data. Now even if there is no matching source data you will still get the month displayed.

```
SELECT
      TCS.departement
    , TCS.category
    , m.mnth AS CURR_MONTH
    , COALESCE(SUM(CASE 
                WHEN BE.DFROM IN ('SEWING', 'WEAVING', 'FORMING', 'DYE', 'HSM', 'INSPECTION', 'WOVEN') AND BE.DFROM = BE.DTO
                    THEN BE.QTY
                END), 0) AS TOTAL_LOSS_PROSES
    , COALESCE(SUM(CASE 
                WHEN BE.DFROM IN ('SEWING', 'WEAVING', 'FORMING', 'DYE', 'HSM', 'INSPECTION', 'WOVEN')
                    THEN 0
                ELSE BE.QTY
                END), 0) AS TOTAL_LOSS_SEMUA
FROM TBL_CATEGORY TCS
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT '2022-04' AS mnth        
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT '2022-05'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2022-06'
    ) AS m
LEFT OUTER JOIN B_ENTRYLOSS BE ON TCS.category = BE.LOSSCAT
                              AND FORMAT(BE.DT, 'yyyy-MM') = m.mnth
GROUP BY TCS.departement
    , TCS.category
    , m.mnth
ORDER BY category ASC
    , CURR_MONTH DESC;
```

nb: I prefer to use (sql standard) `COALESCE` instead of (the properietary) `ISNULL` and I think the second case expression can be simplified to be similar in structure to the first, but it returns 0 if true otherwise QTY.

Comment: thanks you so much, thats what i need, for second case espression its correct to, but i change it to 
'THEN BE.QTY' and  'ELSE 0'
thanks for your help